# Laravel Jetstream Teams not updating

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

I am using Laravel 8 with Jetstream. I customised my teams update form to look like this:

```
  <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
        <x-jet-label for="name" value="{{ __('Name') }}" />

        <x-jet-input id="name"
                    type="text"
                    class="mt-1 block w-full"
                    wire:model.defer="state.name"
                    :disabled="! Gate::check('update', $team)" />

        <x-jet-input-error for="name" class="mt-2" />
    </div>

    <!-- Company Name -->
    <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
        <x-jet-label for="companyName" value="{{ __('Company Name') }}" />

        <x-jet-input id="companyName"
                    type="text"
                    class="mt-1 block w-full"
                    wire:model.defer="state.companyName"
                    :disabled="! Gate::check('update', $team)" />

        <x-jet-input-error for="companyName" class="mt-2" />
    </div>

    <!-- Street Address -->
    <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
        <x-jet-label for="street" value="{{ __('Street Address') }}" />

        <x-jet-input id="street"
                    type="text"
                    class="mt-1 block w-full"
                    wire:model.defer="state.street"
                    :disabled="! Gate::check('update', $team)" />

        <x-jet-input-error for="street" class="mt-2" />
    </div>
```

This is from App\Actions\Jetstream\UpdateTeamName:

```
public function update($user, $team, array $input)
{
    Gate::forUser($user)->authorize('update', $team);

    Validator::make($input, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'companyName' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'street' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'compound' => ['string', 'max:255'],
        'suburb' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'city' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'state' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'website' => ['string', 'max:255'],
        'invoice' => ['string', 'max:255'],
        'quote' => ['string', 'max:255'],
        'vat' => ['string', 'max:255'],
        'registration' => ['string', 'max:255'],
    ])->validateWithBag('updateTeamName');

    $team->forceFill([
        'name' => $input['name'],
        'companyName' => $input['companyName'],
        'street' => $input['street'],
        'compound' => $input['compound'],
        'suburb' => $input['suburb'],
        'city' => $input['city'],
        'state' => $input['state'],
        'phone' => $input['phone'],
        'website' => $input['website'],
        'invoice' => $input['invoice'],
        'quote' => $input['quote'],
        'vat' => $input['vat'],
        'registration' => $input['registration'],
    ])->save();
}
```

This is my database i set to nullable() because when you create a new profile there is no data until you update it.:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->index();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('companyName')->nullable();
        $table->string('street')->nullable();
        $table->string('compound')->nullable();
        $table->string('suburb')->nullable();
        $table->string('city')->nullable();
        $table->string('state')->nullable();
        $table->string('phone')->nullable();
        $table->string('website')->nullable();
        $table->string('invoice')->nullable();
        $table->string('quote')->nullable();
        $table->string('vat')->nullable();
        $table->string('registration')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('personal_team');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

My Model uses guarded:

```
protected $guarded = [

];
```

I swear it was working correctly for more than a week while i was working on it and now it now it just stopped saving the data. The database keeps showing the records as null even after ive updated. The name which is not nullable doesnt change as well, even if i change it in the form and press update. This is the submit button from the Jetstream update form:

```
  @if (Gate::check('update', $team))
    <x-slot name="actions">
        <x-jet-action-message class="mr-3" on="saved">
            {{ __('Saved.') }}
        </x-jet-action-message>

        <x-jet-button>
            {{ __('Save') }}
        </x-jet-button>
    </x-slot>
@endif
```